# Run FlightFinder Blazor on macOS

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm so excited to start to use Blazor and I've just started to play with it. I'm using a Mac and I need to use terminal to create new projects. I've already made the TODO List as described on documentation: https://blazor.net/docs/tutorials/build-your-first-blazor-app.html#build-a-todo-list.

There's a great sample on: https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/blazor. But I can't run it on the macOS. The Server project runs, but the client don't.

"dotnet run" command says: Cannot run your project. Make sure you have an executable project type and make sure that 'dotnet run' supports this project. An executable project must target an executable TFM (for example, netcoreapp2.0) and have OutputType 'Exe'. The current OutputType is 'Exe'.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `dotnet blazor serve`

Comment: I needed to create a Nuget.config file at the solution folder and install the CLI package to use the `dotnet blazor`  command. It worked, but how can I run the server and the client together? I tried to run run both at different instances of terminal. But it didn't work.

Comment: Please open a new question with more details if you need help with that

Comment: That gives me `No executable found matching command "dotnet-blazor"`